# How to update title in react native render?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, jsx, react-navigation-stack

I have a simple function:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        // this.props.navigation.setParams({
        //  title: 'Order: Loading'
        // });

        return(
            <View style={{
                flex: 1, 
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
                <ActivityIndicator/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I uncomment `this.props.navigation.setParams`, I get the following error: **Maximum update depth exceeded**.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: Here you are setting the state inside your render function Due to setting state inside the function you getting the error Maximum update depth exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the approach you are taking is a bit vague, and thats why since you have placed setparams inside your render, so it loops infinitely.

I suppose you are doing an API call and according to that `this.state.isLoading` depends. So now, what i would say is initially set the title of `header` to `Is Loading.`

```
constructor(props){
this.state={
isLoading:true,
title:'Is Loading'
}
}
```

Now suppose you do a api call and you get the result of it :

```
like fetchApiData = async() => {

axios.post(url).then((data) => {

this.setState({isLoading:false,title:data.title});
this.props.navigation.setParams({
         title: data.title
        });

}).catch(err => {
this.setState({isLoading:false,title:error});
this.props.navigation.setParams({
         title: error
        });

})
```

hope you are clear. feel . free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Update your `navigationOptions` with this code :

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerTitle: navigation.state.params.title || <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}><ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#ffffff" /></View>
});
```

Above code will displays the loading indicator(or you can set static loading text) until it don't get param `title`. Now, set this `title` param after fetching your order like this :

```js
fetchOrders = () => {
  const order = await fetchOrders(); // your code to fetch orders
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: (order) ? order.title : "UNTITILED" });

  // Note : Always check if order is available or not to avoid unexpected error
}
```

Don't forget to import `ActivityIndicator` from react-native if you use it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` for this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      title: 'Order: Loading'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: ComponentDidUpdate runs on ever single change so you can not set state directly inside componentDidUpdate function.